# Java Swing JScrollPane not scrolling when shift held down and using mouse wheel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, mousewheel

I have a simple Java Swing program defined below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test main = new Test();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Application window.
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

        // Set up window.
        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,700));
        mainFrame.setFocusable(true);
        mainFrame.requestFocus();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,700));

        JPanel scrollPanel = new JPanel();
        scrollPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        // Add buttons.
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i ++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("Button " + i);
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,100));
            scrollPanel.add(button);
        }

        scrollPane.setViewportView(scrollPanel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(scrollPane);

        // Fill up window.
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(mainFrame);

        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The program consists of a simple JScrollPane with multiple buttons inside of it. Only vertical scrolling is enabled. It works fine.

However, the problem is, when I am holding down the 'shift' key, vertical scrolling does not work when I am using the mouse wheel to scroll. Vertical scrolling only works when I drag the scrollbar or let go of the 'shift' key.

Usually, in a JScrollPane, when the 'shift' key is held down, and the mouse wheel is used, it scrolls horizontally instead of vertically. However, I have disabled horizontal scrolling.

How would I go about enabling vertical scrolling using the mouse wheel if the user is holding down 'shift'?

Comment: You say you disabled horizontal scrolling, but I cannot find that in the code you posted. Can you explain that bit again?

Comment: The code for the mouse wheel scrolling is in `BasicScrollPaneUI.Handler.mouseWheelMoved`, and it strictly says: if the shift key is pressed, only ever do something with the horizontal scroll bar. Therefore your only chance to work around is to disable that listener completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this because normally you would only need the shift scroll when scrolling in more than one direction.

You could try adding a key listener to your JFrame and setting the wheel on your mouse to scroll vertically whenever the shift key is pressed. I tried it with this code and it worked just fine:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.isShiftDown()) {
                frame.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        pane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(pane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue()+arg0.getWheelRotation());
                    }

                });
            }
            if(!arg0.isShiftDown()) {
                frame.removeMouseWheelListener(frame.getMouseWheelListeners()[0]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to add a new MouseWheelListener every time a key is pressed.

Comment: Could I add a line after the if statement that deleted the MouseWheelListener after it had been used?

Comment: Why do you want to keep creating new objects? Usually you create a listener once when you create the component and then just add the listener to the component. There is no need to keep adding/removing a listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. I was afraid that I was going to have to do it this way. Too bad that there is no simpler way to do this.

Comment: @Ryan What's the purpose of the "Auto-generated" comments? Can they be left out? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a cleaner and simpler answer to my question. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CustomScrollPane extends JScrollPane {

    public CustomScrollPane(Component component) {
        super(component);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        // Set up the scroll bar.
        setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // Disable scrolling so we can do it manually.
        setWheelScrollingEnabled(false);

        addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                // Manually scroll.
                getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(getVerticalScrollBar().getValue() + (e.getWheelRotation()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The solution involves disabling JScrollPane from scrolling. It detects when the mousewheel is being rotated, and manually scrolls. This way, it will scroll when the mousewheel is rotated; it does not matter if 'shift' is being held down or not. The only drawback that I can see is that `getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement()` will not change the scrolling speed. The scrolling speed has to be changed manually, perhaps with a constant multiplier.